# Why does 'rmagic' %R cause an error when reading a file, while %%R does not?

Tags: python, r, csv, pandas, dataframe

Using `rmagic` I'm getting inconsistent behavior between `%R` and `%%R` when reading [a particular file](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/15.071x/asset/USDA.csv) (and not others): Why does

```
%%R

usda = read.csv("USDA.csv")
```

work, while

```
%R usda = read.csv("USDA.csv")
```

fails with

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-01ec3b4742c8> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'R usda = read.csv("USDA.csv")')

...

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    458 
    459     """
--> 460     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    461 
    462 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

TypeError: __float__ returned non-float (type rpy2.rinterface.NAIntegerType)
```

Again, this only happens with [the linked file](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/15.071x/asset/USDA.csv), and not with any others I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a missing value handling issue I have seen before. It should happen whenever you have missing values. I am not sure if we should consider it as a bug. But `%R -n usda = read.csv('USDA.csv')` to suppress returning (a `numpy` `array`) using `-n` will avoid the problem.

Should also note, that if you `%Rpull usda` after  `%R -n usda = read.csv('USDA.csv')`, you should similarly get the same exception.

If you want to have the data back and forth between `python` and `R` in such a case, reading it using `pandas` and then `convert_to_r_dataframe` and `convert_robject` will work better I think.

Comment: But why should the same code work with `%%R` but not with `%R`. That does seem like a bug to me.

Comment: The difference is that `%%R` doesn't attempt to return a value but `%R` does and it falls a part when returning the `data.frame` as an `array`. May just as well be considered as bug. But `R` -> `python` conversion is tricky in a lot of case anyhow.

Comment: Ah, I understand now: that's what the `-n` does. Makes sense.